# What is the Difference between r.json().data as Talk[] and r.json()['talk']?

Tags: angular, typescript

What is the difference between point number 1 and point number 2?

1.) `.map((r: Response) => r.json().data as Talk[]);`

2.) `.map(r => this._talks[id] = r.json()['talk']);`

I saw the second point written in someone’s code. Is it as same as point number one?

The point number 2 is written in the Backend class of this link https://blog.nrwl.io/using-ngrx-4-to-manage-state-in-angular-applications-64e7a1f84b7b

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This states that the `data` property of `r.json()` is an array of `Talk` (cast)

1.) `.map((r: Response) => r.json().data as Talk[]);`

This just assigns the property `talk` of `r.json()` to an existing array item.

2.) `.map(r => this._talks[id] = r.json()['talk']);`

These two are doing entirely different things and 2) isn't doing any casting at all.

Comment: What is 2 doing?

Comment: What if 2 something like this? .map(r => this._talks = r.json()['talk']);

Comment: Then `r.json()['talk']` is not added to the array held by `this._talks`, but replaces the array instead.

Comment: It would be better if you would change the question to state what the problem is you try to solve and what problem you run into. Your kind of question isn't a good fit for StackOverflow.

Comment: I don’t run into a problem. I just want to know what does r.json()[‘talk’] do?

Comment: `r` is a reference to an object. `.json()` calls the method `json` of that object and `['talk']` extracts the value of the property `talk` from the value the call to `json` returns.

Comment: There is no talk property here.Here is the type of the talk type Talk = {
  id: number;
  title: string;
  speaker: string;
  description: string;
  yourRating: number;
  rating: number;
}

Comment: This type doesn't seem to be related to 2)

Comment: Here is the link from where the code is written https://blog.nrwl.io/using-ngrx-4-to-manage-state-in-angular-applications-64e7a1f84b7b

Comment: Point is in the Backend class of the code https://blog.nrwl.io/using-ngrx-4-to-manage-state-in-angular-applications-64e7a1f84b7b

Comment: Is there a running example somewhere from that (Plunker or similar)?

Comment: It is only in the link https://blog.nrwl.io/using-ngrx-4-to-manage-state-in-angular-applications-64e7a1f84b7b

Comment: I don't know what to add. it just read a property and sets a property somewhere else.

Comment: I don see a property talk in its type.

Comment: Property or field is used interchangable. It reads a property from the value that is returned by `.json()` and assigns to `this._talks[id]‘. There are TypeScript tutorials out there that get you through the basics.

Comment: The example response can only be like  {
  id: 2;
  title: ‘test title’;
  speaker: ‘karty’;
  description: ‘test desc’;
  yourRating: 5;
  rating: 4;
}

Comment: Please tell me if 
1.)this.talks = r.json()['talk'] and 
2.)const data = r.json(); this.talks = data.talk;
are same

Comment: They are the same

Comment: Thanks. answers accepted and up voted. Looking for my Q to be up voted.